# Mock antd useBreakpoint hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

I want to test the modal component, but there is an error with defining the cancel button,
it renders only if it's not mobile.

isMobile is a variable that is a boolean value from hook - useBreakpoint (ant design library hook).

I don't know how to mock that value, or how to click that button.

Note: if I remove the isMobile check, the button clicks well:)

```
import React from 'react'
import {Grid, Typography} from 'antd'
import {Button} from '@/components/Button'
import {Modal} from '@/components/Modal'
import translations from './translations'
import {ConfirmationModalProps} from './props'

const {Text} = Typography
const {useBreakpoint} = Grid

export const ConfirmationModal = ({visible, onClose, children}: ConfirmationModalProps) => {
    const screens = useBreakpoint()
    const isMobile = screens.xs

    return (
        <Modal
            title={translations().chargeConfirmation}
            visible={visible}
            onOk={onClose}
            onCancel={onClose}
            footer={[
                !isMobile && (
                    <Button role={'cancel-button'} type={'ghost'} key={'cancel'} onClick={onClose}>
                        { translations().cancel }
                    </Button>
                ),
                <Button type={'primary'} key={'charge'} onClick={onClose}>
                    { translations().confirm }
                </Button>
            ]}
        >
            <Text>{translations().confirmationText(children)}</Text>
        </Modal>
    )
}


describe('ConfirmationModal', () => {
    it('should should the children and close button', async () => {
        const onClose = jest.fn()

        jest.mock('antd/es/grid/hooks/useBreakpoint', () => ({
            xs: false
        }))

        render(<ConfirmationModal onClose={onClose} visible={true}>100</ConfirmationModal>)

        const child = screen.getByText('Are you sure you want to charge 100')

        expect(child).toBeTruthy()

        expect(screen.queryByTestId('cancel')).toBeDefined()

        await waitFor(() => screen.queryByTestId('cancel'))

        fireEvent.click(screen.queryByRole('cancel-button'))

        expect(onClose).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
})
```

Errors are:

1. Error: Unable to fire a "click" event - please provide a DOM element.
2. Unable to find an accessible element with the role "cancel-button"

Depending on queryByRole or getByRole selector.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the source code of the [`useBreakpoint`](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/4.23.2/components/grid/hooks/useBreakpoint.tsx#L11) hook.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import useForceUpdate from '../../_util/hooks/useForceUpdate';
import type { ScreenMap } from '../../_util/responsiveObserve';
import ResponsiveObserve from '../../_util/responsiveObserve';

function useBreakpoint(refreshOnChange: boolean = true): ScreenMap {
  const screensRef = useRef<ScreenMap>({});
  const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = ResponsiveObserve.subscribe(supportScreens => {
      screensRef.current = supportScreens;
      if (refreshOnChange) {
        forceUpdate();
      }
    });

    return () => ResponsiveObserve.unsubscribe(token);
  }, []);

  return screensRef.current;
}

export default useBreakpoint;
```

It uses `ResponsiveObserve.subscribe()` to get the `supportScreens`, it calls [ResponsiveObserve.register()](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/4.23.2/components/_util/responsiveObserve.ts#L34), the `.register()` method use `window.matchMedia()` underly. jestjs use JSDOM(a DOM implementation) as its test environment, but JSDOM does not implement `window.matchMedia()` yet. So we need to mock it, see [Mocking methods which are not implemented in JSDOM](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom)

E.g.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from 'antd';

const { useBreakpoint } = Grid;

describe('72021761', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
      writable: true,
      value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(
        (query) =>
          ({
            addListener: (cb: (e: { matches: boolean }) => void) => {
              cb({ matches: query === '(max-width: 575px)' });
            },
            removeListener: jest.fn(),
            matches: query === '(max-width: 575px)',
          } as any)
      ),
    });

    let screensVar;
    function Demo() {
      const screens = useBreakpoint();
      screensVar = screens;
      return <div />;
    }
    render(<Demo />);

    expect(screensVar).toEqual({
      xs: true,
      sm: false,
      md: false,
      lg: false,
      xl: false,
      xxl: false,
    });
  });
});
```